# iPhone location button

Tags: iphone, button, location

Ya know the little location button in the lower-left corner of the Maps application?  Does anybody know where I can find that?  I looked in UIButtonType and UITabBarSystemItem but came up blank.

I'd prefer to use a system image or a system something-or-other, to help ensure consistency with other system functions.

Comment: Toolbar or tab bar? The one in Maps.app is a toolbar.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at https://github.com/myell0w/MTLocation

[image: Idle Mode]
[image: Searching Mode]
[image: Receiving Location Updates Mode]
[image: Receiving Heading Updates Mode]

I mimiced Google Maps' Locate Me - Button, including 4 different states and the animation that is done when switching between states.

Answer (score 7):

You can try using [MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserTrackingBarButtonItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)  It provides the same functionality as the track button on the Map app.  Here is some same code.

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.bottomToolbar.items];
[items insertObject:trackButton atIndex:0];
[self.bottomToolbar setItems:items];
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that in 4.0, the appearance of the "locate me" button in Maps.app button has changed. Further on, `+[UIimage kitImageNamed:]` is gone, and calling `-[UIBarbuttonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem:]` with undocumented identifier 100 will return old-style graphics.

Answer (score 2):

(Warning: **undocumented feature**, will be rejected by AppStore, blah blah blah)

The location button can be accessed with

```
UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:100
                                              target:... action:...];
```

If you just want the image, save the result returned by

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage kitImageNamed:@"UIButtonBarLocate.png"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I created my own image, and Apple accepted it (in contrast of using the search image for zooming purposes).

Answer (score 1):

http://glyphish.com/ icon library has location button available.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be so sure that it's a system image. Many images/buttons in Apple's applications are specific to that application only, and this one looks to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage kitImageNamed:@"UIButtonBarLocate.png"];
// Get the location of the Documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
NSString *imagePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
NSString *filename = @"test.png" ; 
NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, filename] ;

// Save the image 
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
[imageData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
```

use this sample of code to save it as a file that you'll be able to use in your project!

Hope this help.