# What is the name of this Button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, maps

What is the name of this round button in the bottom left corner of this image ?  I would like to use only that little circle button. **How do I allocate it to my nib file ?**

[image: I would like to use only that little circle button. How do I allocate it to my nib file ?]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948329/iphone-location-button

Comment: That's a really old icon. Today it's an arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the locate button, check [this](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIBarButtonItem) to use it. But I wont rely on Apple to approve your app, if you submit it.

Comment: You forwarded me to Wiki page ? Lol. Could you let me know how I can add it to my view ?

Comment: And could you elaborate on your statement "But I wont rely on Apple to approve your app" ?

Comment: Yes, I did, because I assumed you could manage it by yourself to set the Type to 100. Anyway, it's not longer possible to access private button types (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948329/iphone-location-button/3135339#3135339). And, because it's private, apple could reject your app, if you try to submit it to the app store, because the use of private APIs is not allowed.

Comment: Roger. What if I add my own button which looks like that ?

Comment: It's maybe a copyright violation, but I'm not a lawyer (much less for US law). I recommend to create an own image which is inspired by the locate button – don't just copy it.